# Using `:=` from rlang to assign column names using lapply function inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I am trying to loop across a vector of patterns/strings to both match strings within another column and assign the results to a column of the same name as the pattern being searched. A simple example is below.

I am aware that this example is trivial but it captures the minimal case that produces the error that I cannot resolve.

```
> library(rlang)
> library(stringr)
> library(dplyr)
> set.seed(5)
> df <- data.frame(
+   groupA = sample(x = LETTERS[1:6], size = 20, replace = TRUE),
+   id_col = 1:20
+ )
> 
> mycols <- c('A','C','D')
> 
> dfmatches <- 
+   lapply(mycols, function(icol) {
+   data.frame(!!icol := grepl(pattern = icol, x = df$groupA))
+ }) %>% 
+   cbind.data.frame()
```

This gives me the error:

```
 Error: `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument
```

The desired output would be a data.frame like the below:

```
> dfmatches
       A     C     D
1  FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE FALSE
5   TRUE FALSE FALSE
6  FALSE FALSE FALSE
7  FALSE FALSE  TRUE
8  FALSE FALSE FALSE
9  FALSE FALSE FALSE
10  TRUE FALSE FALSE
11 FALSE FALSE FALSE
12 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
13 FALSE FALSE FALSE
14 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
15 FALSE FALSE FALSE
16 FALSE FALSE FALSE
17 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
18 FALSE FALSE FALSE
19 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
20 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I've tried multiple variations using `{{}}` or `!! rlang::sym()` etc but cannot quite figure out the right syntax for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `map_dfc` from `purrr`. Also I think you don't need `grepl` since here we are looking for an exact match and not partial one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_dfc(mycols, ~df %>% transmute(!!.x := groupA == .x))
```

---

In base R, we can do

```
setNames(do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(mycols, 
                 function(x) df$groupA == x)), mycols)
```

Comment: In the real case I'm looking for partial matches.

Comment: @Brandon So `map_dfc(mycols, ~df %>% transmute(!!.x := grepl(.x, groupA)))` ?

Comment: That does the trick! I will have to do some reading to understand why using `!!` works here but doesn't within the expression I originally was attempting.

Comment: Or why, for example, this does not work: `map_dfc(mycols, data.frame(!!.x := grepl(.x, df$groupA)))`, which suggests there's something different about the anonymous function in how the expressions are getting interpreted?

Comment: I think `:=` doesn't evaluate inside `data.frame`. Moreover, you don't need `data.frame` at all here.

Comment: Ah I see. Nice pick-up, this works: `map_dfc(mycols, ~tibble(!!.x := grepl(.x, df$groupA)))`, as does this: `map_dfc(mycols, ~grepl(.x, df$groupA))`, although I don't get the names that way in one command. I had originally used `data.frame` to simplify some of my other code when I had to join things to avoid producing matrix objects, but your approach works much simpler. Thanks!